# Is it possible to change java garbage collector settings at runtime?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The usage of our application has two main modes, one where large quantities of data are loaded and one where the user interacts with the loaded data and wants to have maximal responsivity. When the data is loaded, I want the GC to be quite aggressive to prevent accidental Overflows as new data arrives. When the data is fully loaded I want the GC to be quite passive so that the user may interact with the data in peace.

I have read about the possible options that can be configured in the java garbage collector. One may set JVM options like the following to tweak the behaviour for any given use case:

```
-XX:+G1GC

-XX:GCTimeRatio=9

-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100
```

**Is it possible to change these settings at runtime** to give justice to the fact that I have different needs at different phases of application usage?

Comment: Almost entirely sure the answer is simply 'no'.

Comment: "When the data is fully loaded I want the GC to be quite passive so that the user may interact with the data in peace."


It will be passive so long as you're not loading more into memory? Java's GC is smart enough to only run when it needs to. Give your JVM enough headroom to handle the amount of data you have to load, let it worry about when to run.

Comment: Our headroom is limited:-) See, when loading the data, we do not know how large the incoming datasets will be, therefore it would be advantageous to have minimal remaining dormant objects in the heap to reduce the chance of OME. For that, it would be neat to have the GC be quite aggressive. The GC may be smart, but It can not anticiapted how much data is incoming via the network.

Comment: You can't change the parameters, but you can call a FullGC programmatically: `System.gc()`. Doing that before you load your data should ensure you have the most memory available.

Comment: There’s a fundamental error in your mindset. It doesn’t matter whether the GC is configured to be “aggressive” or “passive” regarding “the chance of OME”. The garbage collector will not throw an OutOfMemoryError when there are lots of “remaining dormant objects in the heap”. It will clean them up first, even if that implies that your configured pause time goals can not be reached, in fact, even if that implies that the concurrent garbage collector ends up behaving like a non-concurrent garbage collector.

Comment: @Holger Lets say we have a solid 30mb/sec allocation rate from the network coming in, and we do not know whether it will all fit into the allocated heap of any particular given machine. Then, when I leave the GC on standard settings it might not behave optimally, i.e., (clear the younger generation spaces of the GC in time), and I would like to tweak it. Why..is that a fundamental error in my mindset? Other programming languages have to deal with these problems all the time.

Comment: You changed the topic. In your previous comment you implicitly claimed that you could get an `OutOfMemoryError` (“to reduce the chance of OME”) if not changing the options. Performance tuning is an entirely different thing. But it’s still strange that you write “we do not know how large the incoming datasets will be” but at the same time believe that you know the best tuning options better than the garbage collector.